# Reduce array of arrays, concat data by dates to week data and sum the values

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I have an peculiar set of data:

```
data: [
  ['2022-01-17T16:29:24', 30], // these below would aggregate to 210
  ['2022-01-17T17:37:24', 30],
  ['2022-01-17T17:41:40', 30],
  ['2022-01-17T17:41:48', 30],
  ['2022-01-21T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-21T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-21T12:50:29', 30],        
  ['2022-01-12T12:50:18', 30], // these below would aggregate to 90
  ['2022-01-12T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-12T12:50:29', 30]
]
```

I would need to reduce this to sets of week data. I would convert dates to start of week to get the week data `moment(day).startOf('isoWeek')` and then concat the data on similar dates and reduce it to single entry.

Ending result would look like:

```
data: [
  ['2022-01-17T00:00:00', 210],
  ['2022-01-10T00:00:00', 90]
]
```

But I am looking for suggestions how to use `.reduce()` or any other more modern solutions for this that would be performant on large sets. Right now I have nested for loops for this which (aside from looking bad) probably perform quite poorly because it iterates multiple times over same array. One requirement is that `moment` should be used for date manipulation, please try to avoid `Date` obj's.

Right now I have something like this:

```js
mergeDataToWeek(data: any[]) {
  let reducedArrays = [];
  for (let arr of data) {
    if (moment(arr[0]).isValid() && arr[1] > 0) {
      arr[0] = moment(arr[0]).startOf('isoWeek').toISOString(true);
      if (!reducedArrays.some(reduced => reduced[0] == (arr[0]))) {
        reducedArrays.push(arr);
      } else {
        let target = reducedArrays.find(reduced => reduced[0] == arr[0]);
        target[1] += arr[1];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(reducedArrays);
  return reducedArrays;
}
```

Comment: Consider a two-stage approach. In the first one, create an object with this structure: `{ '2022-01-17T00:00:00' : <sum1>, '2022-01-10T00:00:00' : <sum2> }`. Then, iterate using `Object.entries()` to obtain the target/desired array. The first-stage can be done like so: `const obj = origData.reduce((f, i) => ({...f, [moment(i[0]).startOf('isoWeek')]: (f[moment(i[0]).startOf('isoWeek')] || 0) + i[1] }), {});`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm trying to solve it using reduce, but the result will be an object. Like this:

```js
const moment = require("moment")
var x = [
    ['2022-01-17T16:29:24', 30], 
    ['2022-01-17T17:37:24', 30],
    ['2022-01-17T17:41:40', 30],
    ['2022-01-17T17:41:48', 30],
    ['2022-01-21T12:50:18', 30],
    ['2022-01-21T12:50:18', 30],
    ['2022-01-21T12:50:29', 30],        
    ['2022-01-12T12:50:18', 30], 
    ['2022-01-12T12:50:18', 30],
    ['2022-01-12T12:50:29', 30]
  ]

// solution
var y = x.reduce((a,b) => {
    const key = moment(b[0]).startOf("isoWeek").format()
    a[key] = a[key]? a[key]+b[1]: b[1]
    return a
}, {})

console.log(y)
```

Output:

```
{ 
  "2022-01-17T00:00:00+07:00": 210,
  "2022-01-10T00:00:00+07:00": 90 
}
```

But if you want it as array as yours, we can convert it by:

```js
var z = Object.keys(y).map(i => [i,y[i]])

// OR THIS -- Thanks to @ghybs
var z = Object.entries(y)

console.log(z)
```

Output:

```
[
  [ '2022-01-17T00:00:00+07:00', 210 ],
  [ '2022-01-10T00:00:00+07:00', 90 ]
]
```

Although it's not the best solution, but I think it will much more readable than nested loop.

Comment: For the last conversion step, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: also can format like `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'` to remove time zone

Comment: I like this. @ghybs the `entries` is perfect. For the string i'd use `.toISOString(true)` where true helps to keep timezone.

Answer (score 0):

---

### ***Run The Code***

```js
let x = [
  ['2022-01-17T16:29:24', 30],
  ['2022-01-17T17:37:24', 30],
  ['2022-01-17T17:41:40', 30],
  ['2022-01-17T17:41:48', 30],
  ['2022-01-21T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-21T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-21T12:50:29', 30],
  ['2022-01-12T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-12T12:50:18', 30],
  ['2022-01-12T12:50:29', 30]
]

// solution
const groupedTotal = x.reduce((a, b) => {
  const key = moment(b[0]).startOf("isoWeek").format()
  a[key] = a[key] ? a[key] + b[1] : b[1]
  return a
}, {});

const totals = Object.entries(groupedTotal);

console.log("Grouped Total:", groupedTotal, "\n Totals:", totals);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.1/moment.js"></script>
```

**Note**:- Code from @Rizal Ardhi Rahmadani...